# Entity Framework Load Error

Tags: entity-framework, load, loaddata

I have this query

```
this.FixturePartidoPuntaje.Load();     

var partidos = from q in this.FixturePartidoPuntaje
               where ( q.FixturePartido.Equipo.EquipoId.Equals(equipoId) ||
                      q.FixturePartido.Equipo1.EquipoId.Equals(equipoId)) &&
                      q.puntaje > 0
               select q;
```

The most important here is that this is a Jugador Entity.

How do I load the `FixturePartido` and ius children?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `.Include()` command:

```
var partidos = from q in this.FixturePartidoPuntaje.Include("children")
               where (q.FixturePartido.Equipo.EquipoId.Equals(equipoId) ||
                      q.FixturePartido.Equipo1.EquipoId.Equals(equipoId)) &&
                      q.puntaje > 0
               select q;
```

"children" here is the name of the Navigational Property that you want to include, if my memory isn't way off...

Comment: I get this error When I add the Include (Compile Time)

'System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.RelatedEnd.Include(bool, bool, System.Collections.Generic.HashSet<System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityReference>)' is inaccessible due to its protection level

Comment: An additional question - did you use the singular or EntitySet name in the .Include() statement? It should be .Include("children") as opposed to .Include("child")...

Comment: In EF 4 there is a PluralizationService that does it automatically.